# How does one calculate the simpson line algebraic?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I would like to apply this theorem to a triangle on the unitcircle:
*Let P be a point on the unit circumcircle of triangle ABC. The
equation of its Simson line is:*

$$2abc\overline{z}-2pz+p^2+(a+b+c)p-(bc+ca+ab)-\frac{abc}{p}=0 $$

Ive tried with $$\Delta ABC $$
for
$$a=-i,b=1,c=i,p=\frac{i}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$$

substituting in the theorem gives
$$-2 \overline{z}+(1-i)z-\frac{3}{2}-4i=0$$
then
$$-2(x-yi)+(1-i)(x+yi)=\frac{3}{2}+4i$$
gives
$$-x+y+i(3y-x)=\frac{3}{2}+4i$$
resulting in:
$$x=\frac {5}{4},y=-\frac{1}{4}$$

How do I form this into a line?

Comment: $2abc=2$, not $-2$ in your first step.